# inexplicable space gap in page

Tags: html, css

I need help with an invisible/inexplicable space gap in my webpage, in the screen screenshots below you can see the space (the red area):
[image]

I need that they behavior just like the other row below "LMP" and "LMB"

In Safari the space gap is not present, but in chrome and firefox this space appears, ain honestly I don't kow what to do, i detected that the `container` class with a `width:80%` desapears the gap, but then the page becomes too thin.

Here is a
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbrh1464/3/)

IF anyone has the same problem, above the titles I have a header, in this I missed a /div so the next row was complete crazy...thanks to all for helping me, i really apreciate the help

Comment: Thanks for perfect edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `div`s have to be `inline-block` and have the same parent.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fbrh1464/6

Comment: Sorry thw JSfiddle was wrong, could you check again?

Comment: @MauricioAndrés isn't your goal achieved?

Comment: No, the error still here, in the new version i no longer have the `col-md-6 col-xs-12`, also I detecten a new behavior, after a screen width of 1397 the two titles are shown in the same row (just is it has to be), but in a lower width the bug appears.

Comment: Sorry,but it's very nebulous to me.Didn't you want to remove whitespace from left?

Comment: Yeah, i need to remove that gap AND to have the behavior of the "LMB" and "LMP" row, I need that "Lo más nuevo" and "Videos más nuevos" to be together in one single row and their content below them

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `<div class="row">`

before any `col-md/col-lg/col-sm` Because Bootstrap keep `15px` **Padding** for this.

Update [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/fbrh1464/5/) solution:

Update solution in codepen [Link](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/NbPpjz/)

And Update **Snipper**

```css
/***** 3.- NEWS AND CONTENT *******/
.news-section {
 background-color: #F1EFEF;
 height: 1500px;
}
.black-title {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    width:112%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-color: #4A90E2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.black-title > h3 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.white-title {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-color: #3F444A; 
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.white-title > h3 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.title-section-2 {
 margin-top:0px;
 height: 100%;
}
.news-content {
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: block;
}
.news-content img {
 margin:auto;
 background-color: #F1EFEF;
}
.news-link {
 text-align: right;
 margin: 10px;
}
.news-link a {
 color: #E7BF3A;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.spot-horizontal {
 height: 90px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #BD10E0;
}
.logos-horizontal {
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #3F444A;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="news-section">

                   
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                         <div class="row">
                            <h3 class=" black-title">Lo más nuevo</h3>
                            <div class="news-content">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="" >    
                            </div>                   
                        </div>
                    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
                            <h3 class="white-title">Videos más nuevos</h3>
                            <div class="news-content">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="" >    
                            </div>
                        </div>
     </div>
                   
                    <div class="col-md-12 spot-horizontal">
      <div class="row">
                            <h3 class="title-black">PUBLICIDAD</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="row">
                            <h3 class=" black-title title-section-2">LMB</h3>
                            <div class="news-content">
                                <h4>Titulo de noticia</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean molestie aliquet tristique. Proin aliquam neque quis est sagittis, tempus sagittis tortor mattis. Praesent nec gravida.</p>

                                <h4>Titulo de noticia</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean molestie aliquet tristique. Proin aliquam neque quis est sagittis, tempus sagittis tortor mattis. Praesent nec gravida.</p>

                                <div class="news-link">
                                    <a href="#">Más Noticias</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>                   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="row">
                            <h3 class="white-title title-section-2">LMP</h3>
                            <div class="news-content">
                                <h4>Titulo de noticia</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean molestie aliquet tristique. Proin aliquam neque quis est sagittis, tempus sagittis tortor mattis. Praesent nec gravida.</p>

                                <h4>Titulo de noticia</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean molestie aliquet tristique. Proin aliquam neque quis est sagittis, tempus sagittis tortor mattis. Praesent nec gravida.</p>

                                <div class="news-link">
                                    <a href="#">Más Noticias</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="col-md-12 logos-horizontal">
      <div class="row">
                            <h3 class="white-title title-section-2">LOGOS</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Of your new Jsfiddle have a mistake     `<div class="news-section">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">`

**change it to Like that's my answer:** `<div class="news-section">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">`

Comment: Could you please check the JDfiddle again? i hace change many things since the original

Comment: [check Update Jsffidle] Solution (https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/fbrh1464/4/)

Comment: What I need is that the "lo más nuevo" and "videos más vistos" act in the same way that "LMB" and "LMP" in desktop, they are shown in the same row and in mobile they are one below the other

Comment: OH! Opps I was miss a `/div` tag , Please check my update answer also take a look this [link_codepen](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/NbPpjz/)